# Video Editing Software with Vector Graphics Annotation Capabilities

Tags: video-editing, vector-graphics, annotation

I am looking for a software (preferably free) that allows me to annotate and draw vector graphics in the frames of a video file. I mean is there a software that combines for example [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) with a video editing software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess **“After Effect”** is the best choice as a software that allows you to draw vector graphics in the frame and also with a video editing. You can study about the “After Effect” from the Wikipedia.And visit the link given below for *free trial version of **"Adobe After Effects CC".***

http://www.adobe.com/in/products/aftereffects.html